# Convert html5 to ios application using PhoneGap in Windows 8

Tags: ios, cordova

Is it possible to make a `PhoneGap` app for `iOS` without Mac? My operating system is Win 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phonegap build is a cloud service.  It doesn't run on anyones computer.

https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: the one i posted is a cloud service.  see the link

Comment: The wording could be taken either way.  What the answer is saying is "PhoneGap offers a cloud compile service that will compile on a remote computer, thus eliminating the need for native SDKs on the developer's machine."

Comment: @programminginallston I agree that, But this statement is " It doesn't run on anyones computer." Confusing. Because you can use phone gap as a cloud service and as a installed one.

Comment: yea sorry i realized that and changed it a few minutes ago.

Comment: My question is not ,Phonegap is cloud service or not :) I guess https://build.phonegap.com/ that's ı am looking for